# How can I save and share the local changes made to a chrome browser webpage via inspect?

Tags: google-chrome

Let's say I go to a wordpress theme website in chrome browser and open a demo.  I right-click on the page and choose inspect, then edit the elements of the page. I change some words, fonts, colors, image/logo urls, etc. and make it look clean for a potential client.

How can I save these changes I've made, and package them in such a way that the client could open the demo url in chrome, inspect, then *load my changes* to see what the product could look like should they decide to buy?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is likely to be creating an elaborate bookmarklet that you would share with the client. However, you should be aware that for security purposes, Chrome requires an extra step when pasting javascript into the address bar. The 'javascript:' at the beginning will be stripped and they will have to type it back in manually.

Another thing to look at is [Jupyter Notebooks](https://jupyter.org/) but I can't begin to explain how you might implement it for your needs. I only use them for python and bash.